# How to make a custom mouse cursor in Java?(Slick 2D)

Tags: java, slick2d

Hello I'm making a game in Slick2D and I would like to create a custom cursor image for it. I would like to know what code and where I need to put it.

```
package lame.game.j3;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState{

//what should I put here?

public Menu(int state){
}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
    //what should I put here?
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{

//what should I put here?

}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException{

//what should I put here?

}

public int getID(){
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [GameContainer.setMouseCursor](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html#setMouseCursor(org.newdawn.slick.opengl.ImageData,%20int,%20int)). You would want to put it in init(...) or in a different class, where the "StateBasedGame" or other game type is created. It depends on where you want the cursor to be used (only in this state, or for the whole game).

Comment: It typed: public abstract void setMouseCursor throws SlickException{Image cursor; int hotSpotX; int hotSpotY;}(I specified hotSpotX/Y at the beginning as 0) in init() but it didn't work, I tried "()" instead of "{}" but that didn't work either, it says void is an invalid type. I have 3 classes, Game(sets up the states and the window) Menu(main menu) and Play(the actual game) I put what you told me in Menu, is that what's wrong? Sorry to bother you again but I really want this to work! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did it by myself, I put this in init(...):

```
gc.setMouseCursor(cursor, hotSpotX, hotSpotY);
```

gc = my game container

cursor = a 32x32 image

hotSpotX/Y= an integer (0)